# Why do I receive a 'RuntimeError invalid SRE code' despite correct installation and PATH variables?

Tags: python, pydicom

I have recently installed the Pydicom library on my laptop. For some reason, whenever I import the module, it displays the error:

```
>>> from pydicom import dcmread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pydicom.dataelem import DataElement
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\dataelem.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pydicom import config  # don't import datetime_conversion directly
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\config.py", line 323, in <module>
    import pydicom.overlays.numpy_handler as overlay_np  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\overlays\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydicom.overlays.numpy_handler import get_overlay_array
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\overlays\numpy_handler.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers import unpack_bits
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\pixel_data_handlers\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util import (
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\pixel_data_handlers\util.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pydicom.uid import UID
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\uid.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pydicom.valuerep import STR_VR_REGEXES, validate_value
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\valuerep.py", line 617, in <module>
    class TM(_DateTimeBase, datetime.time):
  File "C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydicom\valuerep.py", line 622, in TM
    _RE_TIME = re.compile(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 227, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 294, in _compile
    p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\re\_compiler.py", line 759, in compile
    return _sre.compile(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: invalid SRE code
```

When using `pip` to install Pydicom, I received a warning:

```
C:\Users\odonn\Documents> pip install pydicom
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pydicom
  Using cached pydicom-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: pydicom
  WARNING: The script pydicom.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\odonn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pydicom-2.3.0
```

I have added the directory to PATH, but still no results. I have also done a fresh install of Python 3.11.
Neither of these solutions worked.

I am running this code using Visual Studio Code version 1.73, using Python 3.11.0 64-bit.

Comment: This is a bug in Python 3.11 related to regular expressions. It is fixed in [pydicom master](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/1658), and there will be a new patch release 2.3.1 soon (today or tomorrow).

Comment: Update: the patch release is out, so you can just update your`pydicom` version.

Comment: Thank you for an update to this issue! I can mark this question resolved!